# What is content scheduling and how i achieve this programmatically

Tags: schedule, magento-commerce, content

How i apply content scheduling in magento commerce programmatically

1. what is content scheduling?
2. how i implement content scheduling?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a scheduled update instance.
2. Set the name for scheduled updates and define the start date.
3. Set the status of the scheduled update to "pending".
4. Save the scheduled update.
5. Create a cron job that runs every minute and checks for any pending
   scheduled updates.
6. When a pending scheduled update is found, the cron job should call
   the following method to publish the update:

   \Magento\Staging\Model\Update::publish($updateId);

The publish() method will publish the scheduled update and set its status to "published".

Here is an example of how to create a scheduled update programmatically:

```
<?php

namespace App\Code\Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Staging\Api\Data\UpdateInterface;
use Magento\Staging\Model\UpdateFactory;

class ScheduledUpdate
{
    /**
     * @var UpdateFactory
     */
    protected $updateFactory;

    /**
     * @param UpdateFactory $updateFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        UpdateFactory $updateFactory
    ) {
        $this->updateFactory = $updateFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Create a scheduled update
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $startTime
     * @return UpdateInterface
     */
    public function create($name, $startTime)
    {
        $schedule = $this->updateFactory->create();
        $schedule->setName($name);
        $schedule->setStartTime($startTime);
        $schedule->setStatus(\Magento\Staging\Model\Update::STATUS_PENDING);

        return $schedule;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how to create a cron job that checks for pending scheduled updates:

```
<?php

namespace App\Code\Vendor\Module\Cron;

use Magento\Framework\App\Cron\AbstractCron;

class ScheduledUpdateCron extends AbstractCron
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Staging\Model\UpdateFactory
     */
    protected $updateFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Staging\Model\UpdateFactory $updateFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Staging\Model\UpdateFactory $updateFactory
    ) {
        $this->updateFactory = $updateFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Run the cron job
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $updates = $this->updateFactory->create()->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', \Magento\Staging\Model\Update::STATUS_PENDING)
            ->getItems();

        foreach ($updates as $update) {
            $this->publishUpdate($update);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Publish a scheduled update
     *
     * @param UpdateInterface $update
     * @return void
     */
    protected function publishUpdate(UpdateInterface $update)
    {
        $update->publish();
    }
}
```

After you have created the scheduled update and the cron job, you can schedule the cron job to run every minute. You can do this by editing the crontab file for your web server.

Once the cron job is scheduled, it will check for any pending scheduled updates every minute. When a pending scheduled update is found, the cron job will publish the update.